# Context Menu doesn't work with there is Switch in row layout

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have a ListView in my fragment with custom adapter (extended from ArrayAdapter).
list.xml:

```
...
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
...
```

rowlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="60dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alarm_list_rowlayout_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    </TextView>
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/alarm_list_rowlayout_switch_active"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:showText="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Switch>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment.java:

```
...
        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list); //my list
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        registerForContextMenu(mListView); //set up context menu
...
```

If there isn't `switch` in rowlayout than all work fine. But if it added than nothing happened when click on row.
How to solve this problem and use context menu and switch at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to your LinearLayout.

Add

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

to your TextView

Add

```
android:focusable="false"
```

to your Switch